# Style Jquery dialog content div

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have this situation:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id="content";

$(div).dialog('open');
```

The content of the div opens in the dialog but I cannot style it. I tried to access it by id or className. The problem is that I want to have the content filling 100% width and height of the dialog.

I looks like JQuery somehow overrides my CSS. Please help...

CSS:

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Try using !important in your css attributes.

Comment: This worked! But a better sollution would be to find the dialog width and height and set the content to that size! How can I do this?

Comment: I've set width:auto and it fits perfectly but height:auto doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: You can find a particular div's width and height by specific ID using jQuery width/height function. You can have a try with this.

Answer (score 2):

for style you can give like this it may help you

```
#content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a little more advanced but making dialog a little better:)

```
    $("#myDialog").dialog(
    {                                
        modal: true,
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        width: 400,
        position: "top",
        buttons: 
        {
            Close:  function()
                    { 
                        $(this).dialog('close');                                
                    }
        },
        open:   function()
                {        
                    /* styling dialog */
                    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();             
                    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("padding", 5);  
                    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("border", 0);
                    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("padding", 0);

                    $(this).css("-webkit-box-shadow", "0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)");
                    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("-webkit-box-shadow", "0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)");
                    $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("-moz-box-shadow", "0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)");                        
    });
```