# Make JQuery dialog content 100% width and height

Tags: jquery, css, dialog, height, width

I create a div and then open it in a dialog. I've tried styling this div to achieve that the content would expand to 100% in both directions.

What have I tried so far:
Setting the div style

```
#content {
    width:auto !important;
    height:auto !important;
    background-color:red !important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

and setting the default div style

```
$(div).dialog({ dialogClass: 'someStyle' });

.someStyle .ui-dialog-content 
{
    height:auto !important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

Nothing seems to work! I overrides the width propertie but cannot override the height propertie. How to hack this?

I want to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/S3FQv/

Answer (score 14):

You could use the jQuery `width` and `height` properties to get the pixel width of the viewport and apply those as a style to the div

```
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();

//Set up the dialog with the width and height set above.
$('#myDialog').dialog({
    title: 'My Dialog',
    height: h,
    width: w
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/URpmR/2/

You should also add some extra code to reexecute the function should the user change the size of his browser:

```
$(window).resize(myFunction());
```

Comment: @James answer is good. As it's a dialog I assume it is positioned on top of the other content on the page via `display:relative` or `absolute`. A fiddle would be good to see an example

Comment: You are already using jQuery to call the dialog. Why not just apply its height and width at the same time using my method above. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/URpmR/

Comment: I have adviced Jacob the same thing in his previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132096/style-jquery-dialog-content-div#comment21299126_15132096

Comment: Good work, I know you have spend your time on it. Appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order for content to have 100% height, this height must be specified on the `html` and `body` tags:

```
html, body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Also, setting `auto` doesn't necessarily mean the width and/or height will be 100%. Equally, older versions of IE do not support `width: auto;` and `height: auto;`

If possible you shouldn't use `!important` to overwrite existing styles, either.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ryg5y/).

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted... I even provided a working example!

Comment: The html, body properties and removing important didn't do the trick!

Comment: Well I'd presume you were using `!important` to ensure those styles overwrote existing styles. Add `!important` back in and see if it works then. If not, ensure that your dialog isn't wrapped in a container which is set to have less than 100% height and width.

Comment: I sucessuly override height value if set the value to "px" but in % or value:auto soes't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S3FQv/19/ perhaps? I'm not sure if that's what you wanted resizing, however.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` option to `'auto'` as found on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231446/automatically-resize-jquery-ui-dialog-to-the-width-of-the-content-loaded-by-ajax)